# Regex for digits and hyphen only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand regex, for digits of length 10 I can simply do

```
/^[0-9]{10}$/
```

for hyphen only I can do

```
/^[-]$/
```

combining the two using group expression will result in

```
/^([0-9]{10})|([-])$/
```

This expression does not work as intended, it somehow will match part of the string instead of not match at all if the string is invalid.

[image]

How do I make the regex expression that accepts only "-" or 10 digits?

Comment: `a|b` is an alternative: match either `a` or `b`. Here, your `a` pattern is `^([0-9]{10})` and your `b` pattern is `([-])$`. Adding parentheses constrains the alternatives to not include the `^` and `$`.

Comment: If you had looked at the "explanation" on the right side of the screen in regxp101, it would have provide some good clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would have worked fine to combine your two regexps exactly as you had them. In other words, just use the alternation/pipe operator to combine

```
/^[0-9]{10}$/
```

and

```
/^[-]$/
```

as is, directly into

```
/^[0-9]{10}$|^[-]$/
 ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑↑     YOUR ORIGINAL REGEXPS, COMBINED AS IS WITH |
```

This can be represented as

[image: Regular expression visualization]

and that would have worked fine. As others have pointed out, you don't need to specify the hyphen in a character class, so

```
/^[0-9]{10}$|^-$/
              ↑        SIMPLIFY [-] TO JUST -
```

Now, we notice that each of the two alternatives has a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end. That is a bit duplicative, and it also makes it little harder to see immediately that the regexp is always matching things from beginning to end. Therefore, we can rewrite this, as explained in other answers, by taking the `^` and `$` out of both sub-regexps, and combine their contents using the grouping operator `()`:

```
/^([0-9]{10}|-)$/
  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑        GROUP REGEXP CONTENTS WITH PARENS, WITH ANCHORS OUTSIDE
```

The corresponding visualization is

[image: Regular expression visualization]

That would also work fine, but you could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, so the **final, simplest version** is:

```
/^(\d{10}|-)$/
   ↑↑                  USE \d FOR DIGITS
```

and this visualizes as

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If for some reason you don't want to "capture" the group, use `(?:`, as in

```
/^(?:\d{10}|-)$/
   ↑↑                  DON'T CAPTURE THE GROUP
```

and the visualization now shows that group is not captured:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

By the way, in your original attempt to combine the two regexps, I noticed that you parenthesized them as in

```
/^([0-9]{10})|([-])$/
  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑↑    YOU PARENTHESIZED THE SUB-REGEXPS
```

But actually this is not necessary, because the pipe (alternation, of "or") operator has low precedence already (actually it has the lowest precedence of any regexp operator); "low precedence" means it will apply only **after** things on both side are already processed, so what you wrote here is identical to

```
/^[0-9]{10}|[-]$/
```

which, however, still won't work for the reasons mentioned in other answers, as is clear from its visualization:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I am really grateful for such a detailed explanation! Thank you for taking your time to draw out the diagram. This helps me understand Regex alot better! Thank you!

Comment: hey where can i make regex graphs like those ?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make the regex expression that accepts only "-" or 10 digits?

You can use:

```
/^([0-9]{10}|-)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS0xD9/4)

Your regex is just asserting presence of hyphen in the end due to misplacements of parentheses.

Here is the **effective breakdown** of OP's regex:

```
^([0-9]{10})   # matches 10 digits at start
|              # OR
([-])$         # matches hyphen at end
```

which will cause OP's regex to match any input starting with 10 digits or ending with hyphen making these invalid inputs also a valid match:

```
1234567890111
1234----
------------------
1234567890--------
```

Comment: I think OP wants a single -. Unsure... it's unclear... but based on the `/^[-]$/` I believe that it is what he wants.

Comment: thank you this is perfect! Although I am not sure what is the difference that make this example works! Regex is confusing..

Comment: @Zanko: I've also further explained in my answer why your regex was failing. Let me know if you have any further doubt.

Answer (score 2):

To get *the regex expression that accepts only "-" or 10 digits* - change your regexp as shown below:

```
^(\d{10}|-)$
```

[DEMO link](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5nA3/2)

Comment: Thank you this works as well. I am still confuse on the purpose of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is it's looking for strings either

1. starting with 10 digits i.e. `^([0-9]{10})` or
2. ends with "-" - i.e. `([-])$`

You needs an addtional wrapping `^( .. )$` to get this work. i.e.

```
/^(([0-9]{10})|([-]))$/
```

Better yet `/^([0-9]{10}|-)$/` since `[-]` and `-` are both the same.